# How do I write a before-or-equal-date validation that compares to the current date?

Tags: php, laravel, date

I am new to Laravel and am using Laravel 6.x. I need to write a validation that looks at a date supplied by a user on a form (via a JQuery datepicker) to make sure the user chose a date that is on or before the current date. I can't figure out how to express the current date without using apostrophes in my expression somewhere and THAT is going to mess with Laravel understanding the validation properly.

For example, if I write:

```
'sleep_date' => ['required', 'before-or-equal-date: Date(Y-m-d)']
```

that's not going to work because there are no apostrophes around the argument of the Date function. But if I add apostrophes as in this example, Laravel says there is a syntax error:

```
'sleep_date' => ['required', 'before-or-equal-date: Date('Y-m-d')']
```

How do I code this so that it works as intended?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [concatenate](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) the current date with a dot:

```
'sleep_date' => ['required', 'before_or_equal:' .  Date('Y-m-d')]
```

Also you can use the laravel `now()` helper instead `Date()` in the same way:

```
'sleep_date' => ['required', 'before_or_equal:' . now()->format('Y-m-d')]
```

Comment: No worries, I didn't use that rule for a while and went checking in docs. ;)

Comment: @Tpojka - where did you find that in the docs? I didn't find any examples of this situation in the docs, at least not in the validations page, which is where I would have expected to find it.

Comment: @Henry you can find the docs under [Validation Available Validation Rules: before_or_equal:date](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-before-or-equal) there is no explicit example, just an explanation of how it works

Comment: @porloscerros - I had already found that page, no problem. I couldn't see any way to incorporate a current date in the validation so I was wondering where you and/or Tpojka found the technique of using the concatenation operator. Is that in the manual somewhere?

Comment: @Henry Oh well, I incorporated that technique with experience in php. Since in the documentation says "The field under validation must be a value preceding or equal to the given date.", I pass the date to the rule after the `:` [concatenating](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) the current date. And since Laravel brings Carbon as a dependency, I usually use carbon to work with dates and time, or [now()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-now) helper if I just need `Carbon:now()`.

Comment: @porloscerros - That makes sense. Laravel code looks so different from regular PHP code that I find myself forgetting that it uses PHP and can use the same techniques, like concatenation with the dot operator.